# Why am i getting same evaluation metrics for arima model?

Tags: evaluation, arima

So, I created 2 auto arima model using the same data but with a different name. I am getting the same metrics value for the both the model ? This shows that i get the same predicted value for both the models.

i.e. my question is : Is arima modelling supposed to behave this way for same data?

Comment: If the data is the same, why have you expected a different results?